# SourceTree: Adding a custom action to open a file in an external editor

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

SourceTree has a window called unstaged files where it shows files whose changes have not been committed. I want to right click on the file name & open it in an external editor.
So I added a custom action -> Edit -> pathtoeditor\editor.exe $REPO\$FILE.

This launches the editor. But SourceTree also keeps showing a progress bar.
[image: progress bar]
The progress bar closes only after I close the external editor.

How do I avoid this? After opening the file in the external editor, I want SourceTree's UI to return to its normal state without waiting for the editor to exit.

Comment: It looks like the editor is still running. What happens when you close the editor application (not just the window that displays the file open by SourceTree)?

Comment: @axiac - yes, the editor is still running. When I close the editor the progress bar goes away. However, I want Sourcetree to just launch the external editor and not wait for it to close.

Comment: find an editor that return right-away.  I guess Notepad++ behave like that.  Another choice is to write a little batch/script to run the editor in background

Comment: @AdrianShum - the editor returns right away - that's not the issue - SourceTree waits for the child (and all grandchild processes) to exit.

Comment: @user93353 It may be related: For example, my experience of 7zip on windows, if I set editor to notepad, when I edit file in place in 7zip, 7zip will wait until I close the editor and detect change in file.  However it does not work for Notepad++, 7zip thinks I have closed editor right after file is opened.  I believe Notepad++ command is just "telling" the running editor process to open a file.  So SourceTree may not need to wait.  That's just my guess though, as I don't have environment to test that out.  By the way, you should at least mention which platform you are using.

Comment: @AdrianShum - I am on windows. My editor is not blocking. So it returns immediately if I run it from the command line. I always tried running my editor through batch file with an exit command at the end of the batchfile. SourceTree runs my editor. Runs my exit command but still blocks. So it's probably doing a wait on childprocess & grandchild process ids.

Comment: @user93353 I guess I didn't present my idea right: For example, if you are using Notepad++, if there is already an NP++ editor window running, when you do `notepad++ yourfile`, the corresponding child process will end right-away, as it is just asking the already-running NP++ to open the file for you.  However, may I know why you want it to return right-away? I believe the reason SourceTree is waiting for your editor is that it allow you to edit and reflect it right after you close the editor

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question, but if someone else is looking for the answer currently the easiest way to accomplish this is to follow these steps

1. Within SourceTree go to Tools -> Options
2. Click Custom Actions
3. Click Add
4. Add the Caption
5. For script to run, hit the three dot button and locate the .exe of the application you are wanting to open the file in
6. Add the needed parameters to the parameters text box (in my case this is $FILE
7. Click OK
8. Restart SourceTree

[image: New custom action window]

Now if you right click on a file in Sourcetree and go to the custom actions menu it will now have the action you created. Click on it and it will open in the application you selected without keeping the progress bar open for no reason.

Comment: This use to work for me but now I get the same issue as the original poster of the SourceTree window staying open until the editor (VSCode) closes...

Comment: @GazB, strange, I still use this, though with VS Code rather than Notepad++.  I'm on version 3.3.8, which I know isn't the latest version. I wonder if something may have changed in the latest updates.

Comment: Use `"$FILE"` because a file path can contain spaces

Answer (score 1):

Make a .bat file, say..."launchNotepad.bat" like so

```
@call pathtoEditor\editor %1
```

Make the batch file your script target, and your parameters stay as $REPO\$FILE.  This'll make *launching* the editor your action, rather than the editor itself.

This has a few other advantages, like SourceTree picking up on updates to the batch file without having to restart it.

Comment: Already tried it. Doesn't work. Source tree blocks even then.

Comment: Huh.  Worked for me.  I did test it.  (Using notepad++)

Comment: I just now again tested with notepad++. Doesn't work.

Comment: Weird, wonder what the difference between our environments is.  Command extensions making call behave differently or something?  (For the record, I was able to reproduce your issue, too.)

Comment: What did you have to change to reproduce my issue?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I reproduced your *original* issue, where notepad++ locked up SourceTree.  I thought "call notepad++" should fix it, and it did....but apparently not on your system.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that SourceTree is waiting for the launched process to finish (which could be useful - for example when launching a merge tool, or some other task that requires action from SourceTree when it completes).

To launch a truly independent instance of your editor, use

```
cmd
```

as the "Script to run" and

```
/C start "" path_to_editor <parameters> "$REPO/$FILE"
```

as the parameter.

The /C option on cmd causes the command window to close as soon as it executes the start command, and the empty first parameter to the "start" is a dummy value for the command window that will never open. If path_to_editor contains spaces, then you have to enclose it in quotations.

Comment: I tried this and got the same issue, SourceTree blocks. I put `cmd` in the first field and put `/c start "" notepad` in the second field. It opens the notepad editor, but SourceTree remains blocked.